# Get CXXFLAGS from VTK without using CMake

Tags: makefile, vtk

I am developing some software using VTK. I have compiled VTK succesfully using CMake. Now I need to include the VTK headers and libs into my project. My project is using a plain old Makefile. I would like to avoid using CMake for my project.

How can i get the CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS out of my VTK installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be not possible to get the CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS out of a VTK installation without using CMake. I filed a [bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=11446) about this.

Comment: I recently have come across the same problem, however it seems like your issue was closed, what was your workaround?

Comment: my workaround was to use cmake for  my project. i figured that if vtk was a key dependency then i can just as well use cmake. you can try to use the cmake-config.cmake script attached in the bug report as a pkg-config surrogate.